# Excel VBA Selection - Better Code

Tags: vba, excel, range, selection

I just want to know if the code I have below can be re-written in an easier or shorter commands.  I am new and feel like I am not doing this the best way.  What I am trying to do is select all the contiguous data in Column A.
Thanks.

```
Sub colA()

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Cells(LastRow, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

What like this??

```
Range(Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1).End(xlUp)).Select
```

Even then I would avoid that, I would do something like:

```
With Range(Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1).End(xlUp))
    .Something
    .Something_Else
End with
```

Try to only use Select when you absolutely have to.

Even then, this is only going to select up until a blank, if you want the whole data set, this will do it:

```
Range("A1:A" & range("A" & Rows.Count).end(xlUp).Row)
```

You can then wrap that in a with or .select if you need to.

Comment: I didn't know you can nest all those cells statements.  Thanks for the assistance, really appreciated.  May I ask why you mentioned to try to only use Select when you absolutely have to?  I want to make sure I understand the severity of that action.  Thanks.

Comment: I totally agree on the overuse of `.Select`.  I think its use is born from recording and modifying macros -- and then it just seems the normal way to do things.  Applying the methods against the range rather than the selection is definitely the preferred and cleaner way to approach most problems.

Comment: It's slow as it screen updates and uses processing power. Most things can be done without selecting for example `Range("A1").select` `Selection.Font.Bold = True` can be written as `range("A1").Font.Bold = true`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I wanted to show you a possible alternative.  You used the work "contiguous," which to me meant they are together -- and I sort of don't know what you mean by that.  If all you want are the **populated cells** in column A, you can actually select that by using the `SpecialCells` method of a range and then combining formulas and constants -- essentially the two ways a cell can be populated.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set r = Application.Union(ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), _
  ws.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))

r.Select
```

That said, I echo @DanDonoghue's comment that `.Select` is rarely the way to go.  What are you doing with these cells?  Are you copying them to the clipboard?

```
r.Copy
```

Are you clearing formatting?

```
r.ClearFormats
```

These are things you would generally do against the selection, but that incurs overhead and has the potential to incur other goofy side effects you don't want or need.